# How can we increase tableview cell height based on UIfields content sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am new for iOS and in my project i am adding two `UIButton`s and one `UITextView` on `UITableViewCell` and here `UITextView` is growing based on content size because data is coming from services.

My requirement is based on `textSize` - cell height must be increase for this. I have written some code but it's not working. What did i do here wrong? Please help me i have tried to do this since long time but i did not get result.

### my code:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableList = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    tableList.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    tableList.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    tableList.dataSource=self;
    tableList.delegate=self;
    tableList.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [tableList registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    [self.view addSubview:tableList];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tableList);

    NSArray * horizentalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[tableList]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray * verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[tableList]-0-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    [self.view addConstraints:horizentalConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraint];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *Cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


UITextView * aboutText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        aboutText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        aboutText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        aboutText.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        aboutText.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [Cell.contentView addSubview:aboutText];

        UIButton * button1 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [Cell.contentView addSubview:button1];

        UIButton * button2 = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        [Cell.contentView addSubview:button2];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(aboutText,button1,button2);

        NSArray * formulaH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[aboutText]-10-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];


        NSArray * button1H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[button1]-10-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        NSArray * button2H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[button2]-10-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

        NSArray * verticalspacing = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[aboutText]-10-[button1(30)]-10-[button2(30)]"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views];

        [Cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH];
        [Cell.contentView addConstraints:button1H];
        [Cell.contentView addConstraints:button2H];
        [Cell.contentView addConstraints:verticalspacing];

        aboutText.text = @"Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.";

return Cell;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour of tableview is called dynamic self sizing of tableviewcell. Set up your constraints of buttons and textview as given in picture. Disable textview scrolling. 
Add the following in **viewDidLoad()**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: well i am not using here prototype cell and that to i am adding contraints programatically you please guide me in that way

Comment: Just try tableView.estimatedRowHeight and tableView.rowHeight in viewDidLoad(). Also don't forget to disable textview scrolling. You don't need to write heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

In nutshell, you need to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method, get reference to your model to get the text, calculate the text size and then return the height of the cell accordingly.

This [blog](http://www.macspotsblog.com/dynamic-uitableview-cell-heights-programmatically/) will walks you through the programatic way of doing this.